# Auto commit in kafka with spring cloud stream

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I have an application where I would like to perform (n)ack in the Kafka messages manually. According to spring cloud documentation, it should be done with `autoCommitOffset` [spring cloud documentation](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_example_setting_literal_autocommitoffset_literal_false_and_relying_on_manual_acking)

However, in my application, even defining such property the header `KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT` is still coming as null.

Here is what my configuration looks like

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=${KAFKA_BROKER_LIST}
spring.cloud.stream.default.contentType=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.mytopic.destination=MyInputTopic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.mytopic.group=myConsumerGroup
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.mytopic.consumer.autoCommitOffset=false
```

And my consumer:

```
@StreamListener("myTopic")
public void consume(@NotNull @Valid Message<MyTopic> message) {
    MyTopic payload = message.getPayload();
    Acknowledgment acknowledgment = message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class); // always null
}
```

I am using java 13 with spring boot 2.2.5.RELEASE and spring cloud Hoxton.SR1

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found why my consumer was not working as expected:

In my configuration, I have something like `spring.cloud.stream.bindings. mytopic.destination=MyInputTopic`, however, the stream binding was done like this:

`@StreamListener("Mytopic")`

Apparently, the configurations prefixed with `spring.cloud.stream.bindings` are not case sensitive (as all the configurations worked as expected), but the ones prefixed with `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings` are case sensitive leading to my issue.

Comment: MyInputTopic vs Mytopic is a mismatch not just due to case-sensitivity.. might be worth editing the answer for clarity

Answer (score 1):

I just copied your properties and it works fine for me...

> GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={kafka_offset=0, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@55d4844d, deliveryAttempt=1, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=MyInputTopic, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1589488691039, **kafka_acknowledgment**=Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(topic = MyInputTopic, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 0, CreateTime = 1589488691039, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 3, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = [B@572887c3), contentType=application/json, kafka_groupId=myConsumerGroup}]

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void listen(Message<String> in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("MyInputTopic", "foo".getBytes());
        };
    }

}
```

```
spring.cloud.stream.default.contentType=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=MyInputTopic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=myConsumerGroup
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.autoCommitOffset=false
```

Comment: Tested with Java8, Java14; Boot 2.2.7/Hoxton.SR4; Boot 2.2.5/HoxtonSR1 and all work fine.